# React.children.only expected to receive a single react element

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, tabnavigator

i am getting above mentioned error while running my code and have also searched about this error , i do understand the meaning of this error But i am  not able to figure it out in my case.

**Here is the code for index.android.js file** :-

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';


import TabNavigatoro from './src/pages/TabNavigatoro';

export default class ReactNewsfeedDemo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TabNavigatoro/>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNewsfeedDemo', () => ReactNewsfeedDemo);
```

**Code for TabNavigatoro.js** :-

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

import { Actions, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import logoImg from '../images/logo.png';
import eyeImg  from '../images/eye_black.png';
import homeView from './homeView';
import profileView  from './profileView';

import TabNavigator from 'react-native-tab-navigator';

export default class TabNavigatoro extends Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={selectedTab:'home'}

}
  render() {
    return (
<TabNavigator selectedTab = {this.state.selectedTab}>
  <TabNavigator.Item
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'home'}
    title="Home"
    renderIcon={() => <Image source={logoImg} />}
    renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={logoImg} />}
    onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'home' })}>
    {homeView}
  </TabNavigator.Item>
  <TabNavigator.Item
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'profile'}
    title="Profile"
    renderIcon={() => <Image source={eyeImg} />}
    renderSelectedIcon={() => <Image source={eyeImg} />}
    onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedTab: 'profile' })}>
    {profileView}
  </TabNavigator.Item>
</TabNavigator>
    );
}
}
```

**Here is homeView.js code** :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

export default class homeView extends Component {
render() {
    return (
<View style={styles.container} >
<Text style = {styles.description}>
This is Home View , Please click to confirm.
</Text>
</View>
    );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container : {
flex:1,
alignSelf : 'stretch',
justifyContent:'center',
},
description : {
fontSize:16,
color: '#ffffff',
textAlign:'center',
},
});
```

I found one link with same error but it was not answered :-

https://github.com/expo/react-native-tab-navigator/issues/130

please let me know what actually causing problem whey it's no picking {homeView} and {profileView} pages, why it's coming null ?

Appreciate!!!

Comment: Can you share homeView? If it is a react component then you should use <homeView /> to initiate an instance of it. Same for profileView.

Comment: @TravisWhite , Hello Travis , i even tried with  <homeView />  and  <profileView /> , but in that case too i am getting same error.I have updated my question , added homeView.js code , please have a look at it ...Thanks :)